# Classifier on top of LDA topic vectors?

Tags: text-mining, lda

I have training data in form of pair of documents with an associated label - {doc1, doc2, label}. Label is defined as function of pair of documents.

Now I want to build a model which can predict the label given two new documents.

I want to try different representation of document (instead of common ones say TF-IDF). Can I use vectors (topic distribution) from LDA as features for a classifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a reasonable approach. Also try neural network based representations such as doc2vec. I suppose you know how to do the classification part?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I can try other representation schemes also, like doc2vec, avg. of word vectors etc. And for classification part I am planning to use a simple Logistic regression model on top of concatenation of the two vectors (one from each document). Does this sounds reasonable?

Comment: Instead of concatenation, I'd lean towards learning an inner product; have the input to sigmoid function be $x_1^\dagger M x_2$, for a [PSD M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Norms_on_inner_product_spaces), where the parameter to be learned is now the matrix $M$. But go ahead try it your way, see what you get.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this being used as one feature in a paper. But they also used concatenation of vectors. I mean th feature vector was [x1;x2;x1.T.M.x2]. Why are you suggesting use of this as feature instead of concatenation or as suggested in that paper? I mean is there any advantage of this one over that? I am guessing this feature will learn an similarity function (characterised by matrix M) between x1 and x2? I am not sure though.

Comment: That sounds good too.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that. Thanks for your help :).  Just one question,  am I right in my understanding that this feature learns a similarity metric (M) between two vectors?

Comment: Yes, inner products are similarity measures.